# TFS 2012 TF255062 Error after removing 'Active Directory' Role

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Initially, we had deployed

- Windows Server 2012 in workstation mode
- TFS 2012
- SQL server 2012
- Did not install SharePoint nor configured Reporting services for TFS

Everything was working fine. We had users created under Computer Management > Users and Roles.

The client machines was able to connect the server, developers connected to TFS and also to the TFS portal.

Later we decided to move this server to the have the AD roles installed, we installed and installation of AD also went fine without any issues, of-course we had to restart the server couple times and change the AD name.

Then we tried to connect to server with "name" sometimes can, with "IP" never able to, which is quite ok.

But later we tried to connect to TFS using VS 2012 was not able to connect. The SQL server is working fine, the instance name is working fine everything is working fine in regards to SQL server, but still the TFS was not able to connect.

Later we decided to remove the AD Role - which we did!!! After this the users got removed, TFS entire setting got affected and tfs virtual folder under IIS got corrupted, default collections under TFS got removed. In total my entire project is in stake. Even the system name/PC name/Server name got modified. But developers are still able to connect to SQL server without any issues. The SQL server's instance is working very fine.

We tried to repair/reinstall the TFS 2012, we choose the Advance Configuration Wizard and stuck under Data Tier issue. The error detail is very generic TF255062: A connection cannot be made to the following SQL Server Instance.

How to solve this issue???

I have been troubleshooting based on all the details available on the internet but still unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You are in trouble.  It's going to be hard to give you concrete steps without inspecting your system directly.  My advice is open a Microsoft Support Incident, they will be able to work with you to inspect your configuration and help you recover.